# a and b such that A is similar to B

Tags: matrices, diagonalization

Let 
$$A =
        \begin{bmatrix}
        -3 & 6 & 0 \\
        -2 & 4 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & -1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$
I know the Eigenvalues of the matrix are $-1,0$ and $1$.

Let $a,b$ be real numbers and let

$$B(a,b) =
        \begin{bmatrix}
        0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & a & b \\
        0 & b & a \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

Are there real numbers $a$ and $b$ so that $A$ is similar to $B(a,b)$? If so, ﬁnd an $a$ and $b$ that work, explaining how you know the matrices are similar. If not, explain why not.

Comment: May I ask: in what context are you seeing this question? What have you tried?

Comment: This is a direct question I need to solve. It had multiple parts and an earlier part asked me to find out the eigenvalues of A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to solve this. One way is to use the fact that similar matrices share the same eigenvalues.

The eigenvalues of matrix $B$ can be found by solving its characteristic polynomial

\begin{align} \det \left|\begin{matrix} -\lambda & 0& 0\\ 0 &a-\lambda & b\\ 0 & b&a-\lambda \\\end{matrix}\right| &=0 \\[2ex]
-\lambda(a-\lambda)^2+b^2\lambda &=0
\end{align}

with roots

$$ \lambda_1 =0, \quad \lambda_2=a+b \quad\text{and} \quad \lambda_3 =a-b .$$

Hence, for $A$ and $B$ to have the same eigenvalues it must be that

$$\begin{cases} a+b=1 \\ a-b=-1 \end{cases}  \quad \Rightarrow \quad a=0, \quad \text{and} \quad b=1,$$

or

$$\begin{cases} a+b=-1 \\ a-b=1 \end{cases}  \quad \Rightarrow \quad a=0, \quad \text{and} \quad b=-1.$$

Answer (score 1):

Let's find the eigenvalues of $B(a, b)$. We need the eigenvalues to be $-1, 0, 1$, as similarity is a equivalence relation, both matrices would be similar to:

$$\left(\begin{matrix}
-1&0&0\\
0&0&0\\
0&0&1
\end{matrix}\right)$$

$\det(\lambda I-B(a, b))=
\left|\begin{matrix}
\lambda&0&0\\
0&\lambda-a&-b\\
0&-b&\lambda-a
\end{matrix}\right|\\=
\lambda\left|\begin{matrix}
\lambda-a&-b\\
-b&\lambda-a
\end{matrix}\right|=
\lambda((\lambda-a)^2-b^2)=\lambda(\lambda-a+b)(\lambda-a-b)$

As such, the eigenvalues are $0, a-b, a+b$. Setting $a=0$, $b=1$ suffices.

Comment: shouldn't it be det ( B(a,b) - λI ) = 0 ?

Comment: @AnirudhGangwal, both are essentially the same. $\det(-X)=(-1)^n\det(X)$, where $X$ is a $n\times n$ matrix.

Comment: i think i understand. A is similar to a diagonal matrix (say C) having -1, 0 and 1 as diagonal. Now, if B can have same eigenvalues for some values of $a$ and $b$ then it is also similar to C. Since, A ~ C and B ~ C, therefore A ~ B. Correct ?

Comment: @AnirudhGangwal Yes, similarity is an equivalence relation.